# PHP VK API, как iframe приложение

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Господа, есть ли где-то примеры iframe приложений на php? 
Очень нужен подобный функционал, но на js писать логику не хочу - лучше на php, не хочу светить код. 
Через OAuth не подходит

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"OAuth authorization cannot be used from native VK applications"}
```

Следовательно для нативных приложений должен быть какой-то другой путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что вы используете ID приложения ВК, которое имеет тип "Standalone". Для iFrame прилжения есть свой соотв. тип:

[image: создание нового приложения ВКонтакте]

Чтобы скрыть логику приложения есть, помимо серверного, ещё один вариант: хранимые процедуры ВК (см. метод [`execute()`](https://vk.com/dev/execute), а чтобы не передавать код, в настройках вашего приложения ВК можно создать Хранимые процедуры:

[image: хранимые процедуры ВКонтакте]

Теперь к PHP. iFrame приложения хороши тем, что вам не приходится заботиться об авторизации пользователей вообще: они уже приходят к вам на сервер со своим `user_id` и `access_token` в [параметрах запроса](https://vk.com/dev/apps_init). И вы можете сразу вызывать методы API ВКонтакте со своего сервера от имени зашедшего пользователя. На всякий случай не доверяйте просто так переданным параметрам, и вызовите какой-нибудь метод API с переданным token'ом, чтобы убедиться в том, что он настоящий и соответствует user_id.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развёрнутый ответ, теперь стало понятнее.
Т.е. как я правильно понял, что под мои условия, я могу обойтись и без php но сохранить секретность логики в приложении?

Comment: Только вот не совсем правда понял с хранимыми процедурами, скорее всего эта плашка меню должна появится после модерации или что-то в этом роде, но тип приложения всегда стоял как iframe, как и в Вашем скриншоте 1.

Comment: пункт «Хранимые процедуры» не виден для iFrame-приложений. Только для Standalone и Web-site