# Laravel 5.4 SocialiteProviders - проблема авторизации VKontakte: "OAuth authorization cannot be used from native VK applications

Tags: php, laravel, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Использую из коробки: `socialiteProviders/vkontakte`

ВКонтакте создал приложение, тип: веб-сайт
Прописал ссылку каллбек и вписал полученные ключи.

Параметры передаю вот так:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id={Клиент_ID}&redirect_uri=http://домен/vkontakte/callback&scope=email&response_type=code&state={ключ}
```

Выдает ответ:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"OAuth authorization cannot be used from native VK applications"}
```

Читал предыдущее решение вопроса: [PHP VK API, как iframe приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558228/)
Но там нет развернутого примера...

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем пока ждал ответа, разобрался сам в проблеме, все оказывается работает из коробки по умолчанию, надо было только прописать в параметрах файла .env правильные данные:

VKONTAKTE_KEY=тут_id_приложения!!!!!!!!!
VKONTAKTE_SECRET=Здесь_защищенный_ключ!!!!

VKONTAKTE_REDIRECT_URI=[http://ваш_домен/auth/vkontakte/callback](http://%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/auth/vkontakte/callback)

Comment: Ага, и про это в документации прям написано))